# Adding users to Tridion when using SAML

Tags: sites-9, user-management, sso

In the scenario when SAML is configured for user authentication in Sites 9, the documentation suggest to use user provisioning through group mapping.

Is this the only way to go? Apart from using the PowerShell framework or UI extension workarounds, is there a more elegant way to configure Tridion to be able to select users from the domain in the UI? Maybe by configuring LDAP? Although I am not sure if LDAP can be used in combination with SAML.

Answer (score 1):

The Tridion Sites OOTB Installed system UI to Search and add users will not work for SAML enabled system, because of DOMAIN ! = LDAP

if you use Domain users then they are windows users, and you might need to configure the services to use windows auth.

In order to search and add LDAP users for Content Porter, Templating, and core services.

The alternative way to implement to Configuring Active Directory As Directory Service in SDL Web Content Manager Explorer Console.

Used to search certain parameters like Directory service name, Directory server name, and Search Account DN (OU) to search specific filters to limit your search query.

[Configuring Directory Services](https://docs.sdl.com/792149/677735/sdl-tridion-sites-9/configuring-directory-services)

[Adding User Groups from an LDAP directory](https://docs.sdl.com/792149/386984/sdl-tridion-sites-9/adding-user-groups-from-an-ldap-directory)

I hope it helps